# If $zw$ is real, must $w$ be a multiple of the conjugate of $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I'm talking about this:

$$c(a+bi)(a-bi) = c(a^2+b^2)$$ where $c$ is real.

Is it true that  $a+bi$ can only be multiplied with $c(a-bi)$ in order to get a real number or are there other complex numbers that can multiply to get a real number? If this is the only way, how do you prove it?

Comment: This is the only way unless we are multiplying by $0$.

Comment: $0$ is included as the case $c=0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But not in the case $a=b=0$.

Comment: I think you meant to ask if a complex number can become a real number when multiplied only by its conjugate or multiples thereof.  It could also become a real number by adding its conjugate...

Comment: You can also rotate it to the $x$-axis, e.g., $(a+bi)*e^{-i\theta}$, where $\theta=\tan^{-1}(b/a)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, obviously $0z$ will be real for all $z$. For $w\ne 0$, recall that $\frac1{w}=\frac{\overline w}{\lvert w\rvert^2}$, and therefore $zw=\alpha\in\Bbb R$ implies $z=\frac{\alpha}{\lvert w\rvert^2}\overline w$, which is a real multiple of $\overline w$.

Answer (score 7):

If $z$ is any nonzero complex number and $w$ is a complex number such that $zw$ is real, then $w$ must be a real multiple of the conjugate $\overline{z}$.  The quick way to see this is to notice that both $zw$ and $z\overline{z}$ are real, so the quotient $$\frac{zw}{z\overline{z}}=\frac{w}{\overline{z}}$$ is also real (here we use the assumption that $z$ is nonzero to be sure this division is defined).  Since $$w=\frac{w}{\overline{z}}\cdot \overline{z},$$ this says exactly that $w$ is a real multiple of $\overline{z}$.

Answer (score 4):

A geometrical way to think about is as follows: Let $z=a+ib=re^{i\alpha}$, you want to multiply this by a complex number $w=se^{i\beta}$ such that the product is real. This would mean
$$wz=rse^{i(\alpha+\beta)} \in \Bbb{R}.$$
For this either $s=0$ OR $\alpha+\beta =n\pi \implies \beta=n\pi-\alpha$, where $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Thus
$$w=se^{i(n\pi-\alpha)}=s \, \underbrace{e^{-i\alpha}}_{\frac{\bar{z}}{r}} \, \underbrace{e^{i n\pi}}_{\pm 1}=\pm \frac{s}{r}\bar{z}$$